# jquery validation plugin, how can i validate a field but not have it required

Tags: jquery, decimal, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for clientside validation of a form.

I have a field StandardPrice which is required and needs to be a number. The validation code below works perfect.

I have another field in a form called MinPrice that is optional but I do want to validate that if a user puts something in there that it is a number.  I thought by removing the **required: true** but still having the **number: true** it would support this but it seems like its not allowing me to leave this field blank (even though I don't have **required: true** set)

Does jquery validation plugin support validating a field IF its populated but leaving it alone if its blank.

Here is my code:

```
 $("#productForm").validate({
     rules: {
         StandardPrice: {
             required: true,
             number: true
         },
         MinPrice: {
             number: true
         }
     }
 });
```

Here is a screenshot of the validation when the field is empty:

[image]

and here is my html output (my actual code is using a lot of HTML.helpers() and Html.ValidationMessageFor()

```
 <form action="/Product/EditProduct" id="productForm" method="post">    <fieldset>
    <legend>Product</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Product_Name">Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="required" id="Product_Name" name="Product.Name" style="width:450px;" type="text" value="Linzer Tart" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Product.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">

        <label for="Product_StandardPrice">StandardPrice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StandardPrice must be a number." data-val-required="The StandardPrice field is required." id="Product_StandardPrice" name="Product.StandardPrice" style="width:45px;text-align:right;" type="text" value="1.50" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Product.StandardPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Product_MiniPrice">MiniPrice</label>

    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MiniPrice must be a number." data-val-required="The MiniPrice field is required." id="Product_MiniPrice" name="Product.MiniPrice" style="width:45px;text-align:right;" type="text" value="0.00" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Product.MiniPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Product_Id" name="Product.Id" type="hidden" value="102" />

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />

    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number: true` should work as you expect as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FTpZp/1/).

- leave the field blank => the form submits
- enter a valid number in the field => the form submits
- enter an invalid number => an error message is shown and the form doesn't submit

After showing your markup it seems that you have some inconsistency between your field names and your jQuery validate names. For example your input is named `Product.StandardPrice`, not `StandardPrice` which is what you are using in your jQuery.validate. So none of your validate rules actually will apply as it doesn't have any corresponding form element. So fix it:

```
$("#productForm").validate({
     rules: {
         'Product.StandardPrice': {
             required: true,
             number: true
         },
         'Product.MiniPrice': {
             number: true
         }
     }
});
```

Also notice that it should be `Product.MiniPrice` and not `Product.MinPrice`. Please be consistent.

Remark: looking at your markup it is pretty clear that this is generated by ASP.NET MVC 3 HTML helpers. Why are you using custom jQuery.validate rules instead of the default unobtrusive ones?

Comment: i have updated the question with my HTML and an image of the validation message popping up on that field when its empty

Comment: yes this is mvc html helpers.  is there a default unobtrusive way to validate numbers.  The only thing i saw was class="required" to validate field is not empty.  any links would be great

Comment: @ooo, that's an entirely different question than the one asked here. We are getting very much off-topic. Maybe you could start a new thread where you could precisely describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: fair enough.  so back to the original question, i updated the javascript to mimic the "Product.MiniPrice" .. and still getting: "The MiniPrice field is required." when i blank out the field and click form submit.  Here is a jsfiddle as you requested: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9kM/4/

Comment: @ooo, did you read my updated answer? Did you see my remark about your field names inconsistencies? Now please look at this working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9kM/6/ Notice how the names of the input fields must match the names in the jQuery validate rules?

Comment: yes, i read your answer.  My jsfiddle that i posted in my last comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9kM/4/ looks identical to yours in your last comment.  maybe i am missing something ?

Comment: @ooo, something must have changed. When I opened it initially it didn't use `'Product.MiniPrice'`. Now it works. I must have updated it.

Comment: no worries.  Another thing that is weird is that the MiniPrice field is showing the validation error right after i tab out of the field (didn't have to wait to click submit).  not sure if that helps identify what the issue could be.

Comment: @ooo, you could add the `onkeyup: false` and `onfocusout: false` properties to the jQuery.validate to avoid this. In this case validation will occur only when the form is submitted and not when a key is pressed or when the field looses focus. Take a look at the documentation for additional options: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: thanks.  That fixed it from popping up on tab but that didn't solve the problem as the image i have in the question (where it says "The MiniPrice field is required") is now just popping up when i click form submit

Comment: @ooo, in the jsfiddle this message doesn't show if you leave the field blank. I suspect that you have messed up ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation with your jQuery.validate custom validation rules. You cannot have both. Make sure you have disabled ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation in your web.config if you intend to write custom jQuery validate rules.

Comment: I just had another interesting observation.  when i remove the MiniPrice field from the validate() option (and just have: $("#productForm").validate({
             onkeyup: false,
             rules: {
                 'Product.StandardPrice': {
                     required: true,
                     number: true
                 }
             }  I STILL GET THE VALIDATION on the MINIPRICE field when i click form submit
         });

Comment: @ooo, of course, that's because you have MESSED UP with ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation which kicks in. Disable it. You really have to choose: either you use Data Annotation attributes on your view models and rely on the built-in ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation (without writing a single line of javascript) or you do things manually in which case you should disable it in your web.config by setting the `ClientValidationEnabled` key to `false`.

Comment: understood.  as a test i changed MiniPrice datatype from a decimal to a decimal? and now the validation is fixed. So that tells me that by default any decimal field will automatically convert to required = true during validation. NOTE: i have not put in any data attributes or annotations on my properties

Comment: @ooo, yes indeed, value types are required by default. By making them nullable (reference types) you could allow empty values.

Comment: ok so now i have it working (thanks for all of you time and patience) so to sum it up, when dealing with properties that are value types, the "Required" attributed essentially exists by default without any other code. The only way to have the unobtrusive code not validate is to make it nullable

Comment: better late than never :).  Thanks again for your time. MVC3 helpers more "clever" than i realized

Comment: what threw me for a loop was in all the examples that i read about MVC3 unobtrusive validation, they were putting the Required attribute on the number datatype fields in the model.  Here is an example:  http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: @ooo, yeap, there are many examples out in the wild that are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your html. This works fine for me:

```
<input id="StandardPrice" name="StandardPrice" type="textbox" />
<input id="MinPrice" name="MinPrice" type="textbox" />

$("#productForm").validate({
 rules: {
     StandardPrice: {
         required: true,
         number: true
     },
     MinPrice: {
         number: true
     }
 }
```

});

Comment: i have updated the question with my HTML and an image of the validation message popping up on that field when its empty